# Http status 404 -/the requested resource is not available

Tags: java, tomcat

I am new to java, I just tried to read initialization parameters from Deployment Descriptor file (web.xml), But got above error?

My `web.xml` and java file coding coding in snap attached.

My directrory structure is

```
c:\....tomcat\webapps\dd\web-inf\classes
```

No error in java class file.

[image]

Java file code which is compiled successfully

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*; 
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class MyServlet2 extends HttpServlet { 

    String fileName; 
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config); 
        fileName = config.getInitParameter("logfilename"); 
    } 

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException { 
         processRequest(request, response); 
    } 

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException { 
         processRequest(request, response); 
    } 

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse 
response)throws ServletException, IOException { 
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
          out.println(fileName); 
          out.close(); 
    } 
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<web-app> 
    <servlet> 
    <servlet-name>MyServlet2</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>MyServlet2</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>logfilename</param-name>
            <param-value>value1</param-value> 
        </init-param>
    </servlet> 
    <servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>MyServlet2</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/mc11</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

Other detail of my directory and error page i think that my web.xml not working
[image]

Comment: In future, please show text *as text* rather than as screenshots. I'd also strongly advise you to investigate an editor other than notepad for writing both code and XML...

Comment: Please get a proper IDE - it will make your life so much easier. Also can you edit your post so that the code shows properly (by prepending 4 spaces before each line).

Comment: Yes m shaw i edit my post again, i described above i m not good at java its just assignment that i have to submit i am working in vb.net with vs2013.please help me if you can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with code,I try net beans tool and done assignment perfectly with the help of above code.Before that may be problem in tomcat.

Answer (score 5):

There are two problems I can see at the moment...

### Servlet init parameters

You currently have:

//defining param1
    param1
    value1

That's not how you define the parameter. You should specify a `param-name` element containing the name of the parameter, rather than using the name of the parameter as an XML element name.

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>logfilename</param-name>
   <param-value>...</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Also note that `//` isn't how you write comments in XML - if you wanted a comment, you should have:

```
<!-- Define the first parameter -->
<init-param>
   <param-name>logfilename</param-name>
   <param-value>...</param-value>
</init-param>
```

(The `param-value` element should have been a hint - if you could really just specify your own element, I'd have expected `<logfilename>value in here</logfilename>` - having the name specified as an element name, but the value specified with a fixed element name of `param-value` would have been an odd scheme.)

### Servlet mapping

Currently your mapping is:

```
<servlet-name> FormServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ss/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I suspect that mapping won't match `http://localhost:8080/dd/ss/s.html` because you don't have any wildcards in there - it you may well find that it matches *exactly* `http://localhost:8080/dd/ss/`. It's not clear where the `dd` part comes in, but I assume that's a separate part of your configuration. You should try:

```
<!-- I would recommend removing the space from the servlet
   - name *everywhere*. -->
<servlet-name>FormServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ss/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If that doesn't work for `http://localhost:8080/dd/ss/s.html`, see whether it maps `http://localhost:8080/ss/s.html` - it may be that your engine isn't configured the way you expect elsewhere.

Comment: <param-name>logfilename</param-name>
I change it from web.xml file, also from java file, restart server but same error occurred?

Comment: What do you mean by "also from java file"? Have you debugged into this at all? What URL are you requesting?

Comment: My url is http://localhost:8080/dd/ss.
"also from java file" means that java class file after compile.
My directrory structure is c:....tomcat\webapps\dd\web-inf\classes 
No error in java class file.
Is there any problem between web-inf and WEB-INF which one correct?
http://localhost:8080 work fine
http://localhost:8080/dd/s.html work fine

Comment: @SoniaRehman: Well /dd/s.html would go to an entirely different servlet.  It looks like you haven't got the URL mapping right - I'll edit my answer. In the meantime, you should edit your question to have the text as text, not screenshots.

Comment: yes http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet i edit my question with removing previous error, and directory structure dd is folder name, and dd/s.html is shows that server is on.I just test it," s.html is not part of my project its just for testing "

Comment: @SoniaRehman: Now please edit the question again using the preview to check that it's formatted properly before you post... and bear in mind that XML *isn't* a Javascript snippet. You're now showing an entirely different URL mapping, which doesn't help... (And editing your question so that an existing answer doesn't make sense is generally unhelpful, btw...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84061/discussion-between-sonia-rehman-and-jon-skeet).